# How to customize the list of categories in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have the following HTML and would like the output of the list of my WordPress was consistent with it. Categories without children would be within a `<li>` categories with children already enter into a dropdown menu. HTML and JS to all this work is perfect, but I knew not create the function to return the WordPress categories in this format.

```
   <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Categoria 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categoria 2</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Categoria 3<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Categoria 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Categoria 3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Categoria 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categoria 5</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Categoria 6<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Categoria 6.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Categoria 6.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories
try this:

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'title_li' =>''
);

echo'<ul>';
wp_list_categories($args);
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: I will provide an example later this evening (about 8 hours from now)